# Computing weighted mean in pandas dataframe based on intervals

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, `df1, df2`.

`df1` consists of 3 columns, `start, end, id`.
`df2` consists of 4 columns, `start, end, id, quantity`.
Note that `start < end` always for both dataframes.

For `df1`, `end - start` for each row is always 15, and the `[start, end]` pair for each row is nonoverlapping and contiguous for each id, e.g.,

```
df1:

id   start   end
1    0       15
1    15      30
1    30      45
2    0       15
2    15      30
2    30      45
```

I need to create a 4th column, `quantity_average`, in `df1`, where the `quantity_average` for each row is the *weighted* average of all `df2.quantity` such that the corresponding `id` is the same in both and there is full/partial overlap between the start, end pairs in both dataframes.

The weight is defined as `(min(df2.end, df1.end) - max(df2.start, df1.start)) / 15`, i.e., proportional to the amount of overlap.

I will provide a full example. We will use the `df1` above, and use

```
df2 = 
id   start   end    quantity
1    0       1.1    3.5
1    1.1     11.4   5.5
1    11.4    34     2.5
1    34      46     3
2    0       1.5    2.2
2    1.5     20     1.0
2    20      30     4.5
```

So we have the result for `quantity_average` to be:

```
1.1 / 15 * 3.5 + (11.4 - 1.1)/15 * 5.5 + (15 - 11.4) / 15 * 2.5 = 4.63333

(30 - 15) / 15 * 2.5 = 2.5

(34 - 30) / 15 * 2.5 = 0.66666

1.5 / 15 * 2.2 + (15 - 1.5) / 15 * 1.0 = 1.12

(20 - 15) / 15 * 1.0 + (30 - 20) / 15 * 4.5 = 3.33333333333

0
```

I am wondering if there's a quick way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (not so simple) way to do it. It's fast in the sense that it uses vectorized functions but its time and memory complexities are both `O(len(df1) * len(df2))`. Depending on the scale of your data sets, the memory requirements may overwhelm your computers' hardware.

The idea is to use numpy broadcasting to compare every row in `df1` against every row in `df2`, searching for pairs that:

- Have same `id`
- Have overlapping duration (`start - end`).

... then perform calculations over them:

```py
# Extract the columns to numpy array
# For the columns of df1, raise each by one dimension to prepare
# for numpy broadcasting
id1, start1, end1 = [col[:, None] for col in df1.to_numpy().T]
id2, start2, end2, quantity2 = df2.to_numpy().T

# Match each row in df1 to each row in df2
# `is_match` is a matrix where if cell (i, j) is True, row i of
# df1 matches row j of df2
is_match = (id1 == id2) & (start1 <= end2) & (start2 <= end1)

# `start` is a matrix where cell (i, j) is the maximum start time
# between row i of df1 and row j of df2
start = np.maximum(
    np.tile(start1, len(df2)),
    np.tile(start2, (len(df1), 1))
)

# Likewise, `end` is a matrix where cell (i, j) is the minium end
# time between row i of df1 and row j of df2
end = np.minimum(
    np.tile(end1, len(df2)),
    np.tile(end2, (len(df1), 1))
)

# This assumes that every row in df1 has a duration of 15
df1["quantity"] = (is_match * (end - start) * quantity2).sum(axis=1) / 15


# This allow each row in df1 to have a different duration
df1["quantity"] = (is_match * (end - start) * quantity2).sum(axis=1) / (end1 - start1)[:, 0]
```

Comment: I am not well versed with Python and was wondering why we needed  to broadcast to numpy here? Is it not possible to do everything with pandas here?

Comment: Also, the `is_match` gives me memory errors. `df2` can be very large